# getting the password field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

on the following input:

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control">
```

I cannot get its value using:

```
var password=$("input[name='password']").val();
```

is there a typo I cannot see or any other restriction on accessing the type password input value I am not aware of?

It works properly on this field:

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="La tua email" class="input-box form-control">

var valMail=$("input[name='email']").val();
```

Comment: Set value field for password. It will work

Comment: @uks see my edit. the value attribute is not necessary to get the value typed from the user

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/nwfq6908/ what are you doing differently?

Comment: For that, you have to set a change handler for your input

Comment: @Jamiec it turned out I was having two input fields with the same name in two different forms of the same page (the other was actually hidden). It was referencing the "other" field

Comment: @UKS i have the correct event (click of the submit button)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to get the value before you enter it into field. The following example proves that your code is correct:

```js
$(window).on('keyup', function() {
  var password = $("input[name='password']").val();
  console.log(password);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control">
```

Comment: the check is done on submitting a form. So it seems weird to me too. I hoped it was a typo. Will have to debug it again

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '#password', function() {
  var password = $("input[name='password']").val();
  console.log(password);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control">
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this way

```
$("input[name=password]").val();
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything compared to my code. The issue is not on the quotes you removed.

Comment: You have used single quote in a password like 'password' and I hadn't used it

Comment: and as I said, the issue is not there

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani `[name='password']` or `[name=password]` will return the same in this case so that will not be the problem,

Answer (score -2):

Try this one.

```
< input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control" >

let password = $(#password).val();
```